# Creating SDK/API (for Application Development) for My Own OS

Tags: c++, api, gcc, sdk, operating-system

I am Created an Simple OS. I wants to create external apps for it, that should already compiled as an elf executable and can run on my OS, I have no Idea to Create an API or SDK for Successful compilation of apps. How can I make Applications able to use OS Inbuilt Classes and Functions Without Including Headers files of OS.

Like Applications of Windows or Others.

Is I need a Dynamic Library like .dll (in windows)? Then How can I do It?

Answer (score 1):

If by application you mean device driver it is rather complex because you need to link these with the kernel on boot. For example, on Linux most drivers are written as modules that are placed in a specific directory. The modules are special elf files which are linked with the kernel at boot. The kernel knows where its different functions are so it links the function calls in the special elf file with the kernel at boot by using the relocation entries in the file.

For an application, it is more simple but to make it compatible with elf files compiled on Linux you'd need to follow the System V ABI which states the system call interface to the kernel. It is either that or you have to write your own compiler specific to your OS.

I am myself in the process of writing a small kernel. I'll give you some of my design choices. This way I can tell you how I plan to do things while giving the information on how it works.

**Compiling C++**

My plan is to write a full new system call interface to the kernel. I will thus have to write a full C++ compiler to be able to run C++ apps. Normally, how it works is that the OS provides libraries that contain the definitions of the C++ functions. All functions that are in the headers of C++ (that you can get from g++ or from other places) are thus linked with the C++ libraries that your OS provides. These function definitions are specific to one OS or a set of specific OSes which follow certain conventions like System V. Since I plan to follow no convention, I'll have to reinvent the wheel and make a new compiler to work on my OS.

C++ apps are also linked with several files that are mandatory for starting applications. There is the _start symbol which is provided by crt0.s assembly file. This crt0.s file contains several things among which is a call to the global constructors of your C++ app. You can read the following for more info: https://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_C_Library.

Global constructors must be called because otherwise global objects will never be constructed. A global object construction isn't in the path of a function. It thus never gets executed. In my kernel, I didn't add any startup files as I specify the entry point of my kernel as main and I don't have global objects. I thus decided I didn't need them. I do plan to make these available to user mode by implementing these startup files.

**User input**

Every OS needs a way to pass user input to applications. Most of the time, it is OS specific because the user input functions of C++ are just not good enough. For example, in my kernel I plan on having something similar to windows. Every app on Windows are calling some functions in a loop. These functions will poll a message queue for messages and then call the programmer provided procedure with the message as an argument.

Basically, when the OS detects an input, it puts a message on a message queue of the app which currently has focus stating what was the input. Then this application is polling this queue for messages. When it finds one, it will call the procedure with the message as an argument. The procedure then does something in the app depending on the message.

**The framebuffer**

For drawing, it is quite complex especially if you want support for graphics cards. How I plan to implement things is to have support only for framebuffer modes provided by UEFI. Basically, my OS will only use the GOP provided framebuffer.

My OS will provide a library called after the name of the OS which is going to have a DrawFramebuffer() function. The user mode apps will simply have a big buffer in user mode which contains RGB colors for every pixel and then call the DrawFramebuffer() function which makes a system call in the kernel with the address and size of the user mode buffer as an argument. It will also provide a GetFramebufferSize() function to get the size of the framebuffer. The kernel will thus decide which part of that user mode buffer to draw and which not to draw depending on which part of the screen the user application has access to.

It is rather simple in this case but to support more graphics card it is more complex. You would need support for graphics card drivers and probably some kind of way to write the desktop to the screen. In the end, if you don't know how a driver works, how are you supposed to draw the desktop to the screen? This is why I plan on only having framebuffer support in my minimal kernel.

To answer your question, everything is OS specific unless you provide a conventional way to call your kernel (like following the System V ABI). Also, user input and drawing is always OS specific. For example, on Linux it works with the X server similarly to windows. You create a client to the X server and poll the server to determine if there is a message (like a keyboard input) for your app.

Comment: Is there any Open Source OS or Example that done this?